# How to do printing from COCOA APPLICATION in OSX?

Tags: cocoa, nsfilemanager, nsprintoperation

I am creating a file manager where i attach files and folder of any type , i keep the URLs of the file in my application . I have a Print button and depending upon the type of file i want to print that file . 
How can I achieve this functionality?
File can be of any type mp3 , docx etc and many more , how should i know which file to print or not?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K9sJUd6xvP0&index=48&list=PLE83F832121568D36 Might be of use to you.

Comment: Do you want to print the file yourself or do you want to start another app (Word) to print the file?

Comment: depending upon the file extension. For example if the file is text and it should open Word print open. IS this possible?

Comment: @Lucas Derraugh thanks but it will require alot of customization and i only need to open the default print for that file

Comment: Take a look at `NSWorkSpace`.